# VBA to get HTML text

Tags: vba

I've got VBA to open an IE page and nagivate to its results page. What I want to do now is to copy the results of the page back to Excel.

Here is the HTML from which I want to get a result:

[image: HTML I want to scrape results from]

I want to be able to get the $505 which you can see after class "frequencyAmount"

I've been using variations of the following code with no luck (it executes but no value is pasted into Excel):

```
Cells(1, 22).Value = IE.Document.getElementByID("result-row0").getElementsByClassName("frequencyAmount").outerText
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a *collection* of elements (even if there's only one match)  Try `.getElementsByClassName("frequencyAmount")(0).outerText`

Comment: Ah, great - works - thanks Tim!